# SSRS Add Blank Page After Every Page

Tags: reporting-services, printing, parameters, ssrs-2008, page-break

I have a requirement to insert a blank page after every page when an SSRS report is printed/exported to PDF, however this needs to be controlled via a parameter.

The reason for this requirement is that when the report is printed each page of data needs to be printed onto a separate piece of paper, however the majority of printers are set to double sided by default. Users aren't able to change the default setting except on each occasion they print. Unfortunately this double sided print setting isn't applied everywhere so there needs to be an ability to control the addition/removal of blank pages.

I am able to force a blank page to be created after every page by simply setting the size of the report bigger than the page size, though it isn't possible to control page width size via an expression.

My only thought is that this may be possible via custom code but don't really know where to start with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the table properties, you can set an expression for the Page Break Disabled property. This will allow you to disable / enable a page break based on a parameter. In this example I created a boolean parameter called Break. If its set the parameter to True, you will get an additional page after your table. Hope this can get you started!

[image]